# changing the values of a constant Mat opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to add 180 to a constant Mat in opencv. 
Since I can't change constant values I want to save it into a temp Mat and then add 180 to the value. 
However when I try it , I get negative results when I print out the values.

If I add 180 to temp and print it out, I get undesired output, which are negative numbers.

If I add 180 to dir , I get the correct values and positive numbers.

Am I assigning the values wrong to temp?

```
Mat y(const Mat &image, const Mat &dir) {

  image.copyTo(non_max_sup);
  Mat temp ( dir.size(), CV_32F, Scalar(0));
   dir.copyTo(temp);
  for ( int x = 0; x < dir.rows; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < dir.cols; y++) {


        if(dir.at<int>(x,y)<0){

        temp.at<int>(x,y)=  (dir.at<int>(x,y));



            temp.at<int>(x,y)=temp.at<int>(x,y)+180;

            std::cout<<temp.at<float>(x,y)<<std::endl; //wrong numbers
            //std::cout<<dir.at<float>(x,y)+180<<std::endl; correct numbers

        }

}
}


}
```

Comment: Assuming `dir` has depth of `CV_32F` (since you say `dir.at<float>(x,y)+180` gives correct value, using `dir.at<int>` and `temp.at<int>` is wrong -- you're reinterpreting the floating point value as integer, and doing integer math on it, then reinterpret the result as float again... no suprise you get nonsense out of that.

Comment: Also, for some reason you pre-allocate `temp` and set all values to zero, only to overwrite all of them in the next statement with `dir.copyTo(temp);`. As if that wasn't enough, you overwrite them yet again in the loop with exactly same value...